# Oracle jet connection with Oracle database without using REST API simple example

Tags: oracle, oracle-jet

I am able to connect to an Oracle database using the REST API, but I want to connect to it without the REST API. Is there any another way to connect to an Oracle database?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The short answer, No.

Oracle JET is a pure client-side toolkit.  It does not run or process on the server.  Because of that, the only interaction with data resources is via Web Services of some kind.  REST is the most common.  You could use WebSocket, or Server Sent Events as well, or some other method that a pure client could communicate with.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to get rid of creating a REST API endpoint in your middleware *by hand*?

If the answer is yes, then you could use this: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/rest-data-services/overview/index.html

If the answer is no, then sorry, no. Practically, that is the only way to fetch data from the server.